# How to get a String from h2 database (Java, DBUtil)

Tags: java, database, h2, statements

This is the code from DBUtil

```
public class DBUtil {
    static Connection conn = null;
    public static Connection getConnected() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test", "sa", "");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }//end method
}//end DBUtil
```

and here is the code from the method I'm trying to use:

```
private class SearchForEdit implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String clientNumber = tfieldMiniSearchNumber.getText();
            int number;

            conn = DBUtil.getConnected();
            if(conn == null) return;

            String names=null, address=null;


            String sql ="select names from clients where client_number = ?;";
            String sql2 ="select address from clients where client_number = ?;";

            try {
                state = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                state.setInt(1, number);
                state.execute();

                state = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
                state.setInt(1, number);
                state.execute();

                labelWarning.setForeground(new Color(22, 205, 5));
                labelWarning.setText("<html>TEXT SUCCESS</html>");

                //names = select names from clients where client_number = number;
                //address = select address from clients where client_number = number;

                //if(names!=null && address!=null)

                //tfieldEditClientNumber to be number
                tfieldEditClientNumber.setText(""+number);
                //tfieldEditNames to be names, where names = select names from clients where client_number = number;
                //tfieldEditAddressда to be address, where address = select address from clients where client_number = number;
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                labelWarning.setForeground(Color.RED);
                labelWarning.setText("<html>Try again later</html>");
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
    }//end
```

I want to take the value of column NAME from the database and then put in in the string name. Then the same for address. I know only how to execute statements. Any help is very apreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the results of the query in a `ResultSet`, and then iterate over that `ResultSet`. You can assign the values from the `ResultSet` into variables as you iterate over them.

**Below code is an example of iterating over a**  `ResultSet`, as mentioned in my comment below.

```
while (rs.next()) {
// ResultSet columns: 1 = UserName 2 = FirstName 3 = LastName  4 = Organization
            userInfo[0] = rs.getString(1); // assign UserName result to variable
            userInfo[1] = rs.getString(2); // assign First_Name result to variable
            userInfo[2] = rs.getString(3); // assign Last_Name result to variable
            userInfo[3] = rs.getString(4); // assign Organization result to variable
}
```

The while loop will end when there are no `ResultSet` rows left to iterate over.

Comment: try {
state = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
state.setInt(1, number);
rs1 = state.executeQuery();
System.out.println(rs1.getString("NAMES"));
names = rs1.getString(1);
tfieldEditClientNumber.setText(""+number);
tfieldEditNames.setText(names);
} catch (SQLException e1) {
labelWarning.setForeground(Color.RED);
labelWarning.setText("<html>Error!</html>");
e1.printStackTrace();
}

But it gives me org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: No data is available [2000-196]

The result has 1 column and 1 row when i trie to syso the rs1. Any idea how I should proceed?

Comment: So there are 2 things missing. After you executeQuery(), you need to position the ResultSet so that it has visiblity of the first result, to do that you would use rs1.next(). After that you will need to change the rs1.getString("NAMES") to instead be rs1.getString(1). The resultSet starts at '1', and goes up for each COLUMN in that ROW of the resultSet.  So your first result is in Column1, second result is in Column2, etc. Until you call .next() again, now you are in row 2. Most common way to iterate over a ResultSet is a while loop, but for now focus on just getting the results you want.

Comment: Very helpful! So I just checked if(rs.next()) string = rs.getString(1); which goes to the next result of the result if it exists, if not my string is null. A big misconception from me abour the iterator.